# Let $\deg$ be the topological degree. Then $\deg(fg) = \deg(f)\deg(g)$, with $f, g : M \to N$

Tags: differential-topology

Recall that the topological degree is defined as:

Let $f : M \to N$ a $C^k$ function and $y$ be a regular value of $f$.

Then we define:

$$\deg(f)= \sum_{f(x) = y}|Df(x)|,$$ where $| . |$ means the signal, being $1$ or $-1$ depending if $Df(x)$ preserves or not orientation.

How to show that

$\deg(fg) = \deg(f)\deg(g)$, with $f, g : M \to N$?

Comment: What does $fg$ mean? Do you instead want to show $\deg(f\circ g) = \deg(f)\deg(g)$?

Comment: Yeah I actually haven't read that seems to be a "multiplication". If you don't mean composition, I'll delete the answer

Comment: I mean the composition! I am sorry, and thanks @Riccardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to compute the degree of the **composition of maps**, otherwise please reformulate

if you spell out the definition the proof is easy.

So let me give you some advices:

- Let $M \xrightarrow{f} N \xrightarrow{g} O$ be your composition, let $z\in O$ be a regular value for $gf$. Then set $\{y_i\}_1^n$ as the preimage of $g^{-1}(z)$ and $\{x^i_j\}_1^n$ as the preimage of $f^{-1}(y_i)$. Notice that $\{x^i_j\}_{i,j}=(gf)^{-1}(z)$
- Notice $|D(gf)(x^i_j)|=|D(g)(y_i)||D(f)(x_j^i)|$ (chain rule)
- Conclude